# How to use Django's APIRequestFactory with an array of objects?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following test

```
def test_bulk_post(my_faker,factory):
    snippets = [{'code':'print(True)'},{'code':'print(True)'},{'code':'print(True)'}]
    assert factory.post('/snippets/',snippets) == True
```

I am trying to extend the snippets app in the tutorial to accept multiple code objects in a single post request.

Right now this gives me:

```
/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/client.py(244)encode_multipart()

*** AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

so its not expecting a list.. But I want to give it one. How do I do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by array of objects, are you trying to send JSON ?

Comment: @iklinac see that array in my snippets variable? Those are what I hope to make into Snippet objects. I would like to post them all at once rather than 1 by 1. I also tried doing json.dumps(snippets) but then I get *** AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: This does not look like form encoded data, that is why I am asking if you are trying to POST them as JSON body

Comment: @iklinac. yes I am trying to post them as a json body. I believe thats what the APIRequestFactory's .post() method will do, though Im basically not sure how to use this .post() method with an array like what I have. Does that clarify the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

factory.post by default expects a key, value pairs  that goes with  `multipart/form-data`  and not list hence error

You should probably set `content_type='application/json'` to pass data as JSON body

```
factory.post('/snippets/',snippets, content_type='application/json )
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like you can also specify format='json' rather than the content_type. I was confused especially because its hard to find documentation on the APIRequestFactory, but it seems like the api client methods kinda of work the same way? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/

Comment: Yes, it works in similar fashion but without the actual request being made, in a moment I though you were using Django RequestFactory which does not have format parameter and not DRF one  APIRequestFactory